# Intellij IDEA Contract false-positive syntax error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, contract

I'm getting error although I'm doing it right(I think)

```
@Contract("!null -> !null, _, _, _; null -> null, _, _, _")
public <T> T deserialize(@Nullable final Object object, @Nullable final GenericDeclaration genericSource, @NotNull final Class<T> targetClass, @Nullable final GenericDeclaration genericTarget) {
```

Basically, I'm trying to create a contract for if first parameter is null returns null, otherwise not null. But I don't want to add other parameters into contract, or just ignore it with `_` key.

Intellij IDEA version is 2021.1.2(latest release)

It complains about return values and I don't know why?

[yellow error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFdEU.png)

Comment: The return value goes *after* the signature, as in [the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/contract-annotations.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Contract("!null, _, _, _ -> !null; null, _, _, _ -> null");
```

I guess. Parameter list -> Result ; ... See [Syntax](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/contract-annotations.html#syntax).

Comment: Oh, so there should be only 1 return value for a clause.

Comment: @portlek There *can* be only one return value; it's Java.